# Find the smallest group of numbers with sum bigger then $X$

Tags: subset-sum, summation

Given a list of numbers $S$ where $0 < s_i < 100$, find the minimum sum group of numbers with a sum bigger than $X$.
Each number can be used multiple times.

Ex: for $S = [3,4.1], X = 10$ the solution is $[3, 3, 4.1]$

Is it a known problem? What will be the best way of solving it?

For now, my best solution is to randomly pick numbers and repeat the process multiple times.

Comment: Is it possible to assume that the numbers are integers? (For example, if the numbers are rationals, we can transform the problem by multiplying them by a suitable constant, and dropping the constraint $s_i < 100$).

Comment: @Steven the constrain can be dropped, but I need a big precision, something like 6-8 digits after the point.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What's preventing you from selecting $\left\lceil \frac{X}{\max_i s_i} \right\rceil$ copies of $\max_i s_i$?

Comment: @Steven that solution does not work with my example

Comment: Sure it does. $\lceil 10/4.1 \rceil = 3$, and your solution uses $3$ elements. Maybe you are not looking for the smallest group of elements with sum at least $X$, but rather for a group of elements with sum $\sigma > X$ that minimizes $\sigma$.

Comment: With your conditions, just pick the largest element and repeat it as often as needed. I wouldn't call it a "problem".

Comment: @gnasher729 it will not work with my example, because it will not be the minimal sum above X

Comment: @IlyaGazman, you realize that's not what you asked for, right?

Comment: @Steven I do now! Tnx. Updated the question

Comment: Well, now it looks quite NP-complete to me :)

Comment: @gnasher729 probably NP-hard, I just asked about it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3763270/101178

Comment: “Now it looks NP-complete to me” means it _is_ NP-complete. The special case that all numbers are integers is NP complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for $S' \subset S$ with minimal $\sum_{x \in S'} x > X$ like Steven suggested, then you should be able to reduce the problem to an instance of knapsack with weights $w_i$ and costs $c_i$ with $w_i = c_i = s_i$ for every $s_i \in S$ where the weight of the knapsack is bounded by $X$.

If the solution $K := \sum_{x \in S'} x$ is not greater than $X$, you need to repeat the process by setting $X := X + \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is the minimal distance between any two subset sums of $S$ and running knapsack again until it yields a solution $K > X$.

**Edit:** Turns out that finding $\varepsilon$ isn't an easy problem. I first assumed $\varepsilon$ is the minimum between any two numbers in $S$, which can be found by sorting the list and finding the minimum between two adjacent elements. This would yield a good approximation in most cases, but it might not be the optimal solution. If your problem statement uses $\geq$ instead of $>$, transforming the problem into knapsack will yield an optimal solution, no repetitions required.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It is a special case of knapsack problem where weights equal to costs. The problem is that I can't use a DP to solve this as I deal with real numbers. Don't have enough memory to convert them to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that all involved numbers are positive integers and let $n=|S|$.
From the comments to your question, I understand your problem as follows:

> Given a set $S = \{s_1, \dots, S_n\}$ find a multiset $S'$ such that
> (i) each element of $S'$ belongs to $S$,( ii) the sum $\sigma$ of the
> elements in $S'$ is larger than $X$, and (iii) $S'$ minimizes
> $\sigma$.

You can solve the above problem in time $O(nX)$ with a dynamic programming algorithm.

For an integer $w < X$, let $OPT[w]$ be true ($\top$) if it is possible to select a group of numbers with a total sum of $w$, and false ($\bot$) otherwise.

For $w < 0$ we have $OPT[w] = \bot$. Moreover $OPT[0]= \top$ and, for $w>0$:
$$
OPT[w] = \bigvee_{i=1,\dots,n} OPT[w-s_i].
$$

The minimum attainable sum $\sigma$ that is larger than $X$ is then:
$$
\min_{i=1,\dots,n} \min_{\substack{j = X-s_i+1, \dots, X \\ OPT[j]=\top}} (j+s_i).
$$

The actual group of numbers that sum to $\sigma$ can be found by retracing (backwards) the dynamic programming choices.

Answer (score 1):

If each number can be selected once, it is exactly the knapsack problem (known to be NP-complete): Just turn it on its head, and ask for the numbers *left out*, they are the set with the largest sum less than $S - X$, where $S$ is the sum of all numbers. Exactly the knapsack problem.

Comment: Are there known algorithms for solving the knapsack problem with big integer values as a weight?